# Etymology of the word "Alambric"

Tags: meaning, etymology

I saw the words "Alambric" and "Inalambric" in use on a forum recently and was surprised to find no results on Dictionary.com or Merriam-Webster. It seems to mean "wired" and "wireless" respectively. Google seems to understand the words as wired and wireless and returns results but also doesn't have any results regarding the definition or origin of the words. I'm very curious as to where they came from and why they're not in the dictionary.

Comment: @Nathan please quote your sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Latin *aerāmen*, accusative *aerāminem*, "bronze", entering Spanish as *arambre*, "wire" (compare Latin *nominem* -> Spanish *nombre*, "name", or latin *hominem* -> Spanish *hombre*, "man). http://dle.rae.es/?id=3OmdsSM

Following that, *arambre* became the Spanish word for "wire" as it is today, *alambre*. http://dle.rae.es/?id=1Ry62WZ Spanish sometimes confuses r's and l's in words that have more than one of them: *Argelia* (Algeria), *milagro* (miracle), plus the old favorite *coronel* (from which we got our pronunciation of "colonel").

From *alambre*, Spanish has adjectives *alámbrico* and *inalámbrico*. http://dle.rae.es/?id=LAi5Jpk I hadn't been aware of the use of cognate words in English.

Comment: This is a good answer (I <3 references). I think I know what's happening. "Alambric" and "inalambric"are **not** words in English, but rather errors made by Spanish speakers who think they're words. Nobody except Spanish speakers will know what you're talking about if you use either word in English.

Comment: I think you're correct. I just checked the Oxford English Dictionary, and even that comprehensive work doesn't have an entry for "alambric".

Comment: Philip Pullman in His Dark Materials trilogy refers to electricity as anbaricity, or anbaric power - I guess he may have been influenced by the Spanish, or your speaker influenced by Philip Pullman.

Comment: "Anbaracity" is unrelated. "Electricity" comes from "elektron" (ἤλεκτρον), Greek for "amber". Amber manifests the sort of attraction caused by static electricity when rubbed. In turn, "amber" is derived from "ʕanbar" (عنبر), Arabic for "ambergris". Pullman generated a whole litany of alternative terminology based on alternative etymologies, including "anbaricity" for "electricity". (The [ʕ] sound is like a voiced "h" and usually omitted in English transcriptions and pronunciation--for example, it's the first sound in the Arabic names for "Arab", "Iraq", "Abdullah", and "Omar".)